# Problem with implementing unitroot function in R

Tags: r

I am new to programming, and I have been exposed to the basic of R and Python. I have been trying to implement the volatility smile function using a unit root function(a traditional procedure) but I am running into problems. Here is the code I am writing:

```
BlackScholesFormulaBach  <- function (spot,timetomat,strike,r, q=0, sigma)
{ 
  
  d1<-(spot-strike)/(sigma*sqrt(timetomat))
  d2<-(spot-strike)/(sigma*sqrt(timetomat))
  
  
  result<-(spot-strike)*pnorm(d1)+sigma*sqrt(timetomat)*dnorm(d1)
  
  
  BlackScholesFormulaBach<-result
  
}

BlackScholesImpVol  <- function (obsprice,spot,timetomat,strike,r, q=0)
  
{ difference<- function(sigBS, obsprice,spot,timetomat,strike,r,q)
{BlackScholesFormulaBach(spot,timetomat,strike,r,q,sigBS)-obsprice
}

uniroot(difference, c(-1,1),obsprice=obsprice,spot=spot,timetomat=timetomat,strike=strike,r=r,q=q)$root

}

S_0<-100
cap_T<-1
sigma_1<-15
N<-1000

BlackScholesImpVol(S_0,cap_T,1,0,0,15)
```

Every time I run the code I get:

```
Error in c(-1, 1) : unused argument (1)
```

If I change the interval I get the same error. I have been checking the code but it seems right. I have consulted other people and none finds the problem. According to R the problem is on the unitroot function, but I fail to see where.

Question:

Can someone help me solve this implementation problem?

Thanks in Advnace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you get that error is if you have accidentally [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the R function `c`.

For example,

```
uniroot(sin,c(-1,1))
```

is unproblematic. But

```
c <- function(x) x^2
uniroot(sin(c(-1,1))
```

leads to exactly the same error that you have.
The solution is to, in the console, first evaluate

```
rm(c)
```

and then your function should work (or at the very least not throw the same error). If you actually need this function `c`, you of course might want to assign it to a different name before removing it.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I found out I have defined in another page the function c. I have just removed with it with "rm" and it is working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let the function return a result, and you'll get a result. You can rewrite your other functions just like the one below and they should work.

```
BlackScholesFormulaBach  <-
  function (spot, timetomat, strike, r, q = 0, sigma) {
    d1 <- (spot - strike) / (sigma * sqrt(timetomat))
    d2 <- (spot - strike) / (sigma * sqrt(timetomat))
    result <-
      (spot - strike) * pnorm(d1) + sigma * sqrt(timetomat) * dnorm(d1)
    return(result)
  }

S_0 <- 100
cap_T <- 1
sigma_1 <- 15
N <- 1000

> BlackScholesFormulaBach(S_0, cap_T, 1, 0, 0, 15)
[1] 99
```

Comment: There was a mistake in the question I asked. The function that is not working is BlackScholesImpVol. Please see my edit. Thanks for your answer!